# SQL Server "Cannot generate SSPI context" possible root cause from domain account/permission?

Tags: sql-server

I see the official document about troubleshooting the windows SQL login problem, as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/cannot-generate-sspi-context-error#fix-the-error-with-kerberos-configuration-manager-recommended).

I'm administrating an environment of Windows server 2019 + SQL server 2019 and all the hosts are within a Windows AD domain for centralized management.
A specific domain user account has been grouped into the "domain admins" group and this account is specialized for SQL database to use.

Please note that a domain group policy setting: `windows configuration\windows settings\security settings\local policies\User Rights Assignments\Log on as a service` has been configured with `"<mydomain>\Domain Admins","LOCAL SERVICE" ,"NETWORK SERVICE" ,"NT SERVICE\ALL SERVICES" ,"NTLM Authentication" and "SYSTEM"`

Here is the issue:
There's no problem log-in any SQL hosts with that specific domain user account and also connecting to the local SQL via SSMS + windows authentication.

However, when trying to switch the SQL always on to another DB, the failover wizard show error when connecting to the secondary SQL (located on secondary host), which is "Cannot generate SSPI context". And also, connecting from a SQL host to another SQL host using SSMS showed same issue.

Please note that a weird part is: if I login SSMS with "SQL server authentication", the database can be failover to another SQL host without any problem. And there's no connectivity issue between SQL hosts via SSMS.

I did basic pings between SQL hosts and of course the host name resolution are correct from both sides. Further SQL trace and check will be done.
I would like to troubleshooting the domain user account related permissions and settings first but not sure which part am I missing.

Can anyone give me some hints please?